# C++ general question

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
Miner::Miner(int id):BaseGameEntity(id),
                     m_Location(shack),
                     m_iGoldCarried(0),
                     m_iMoneyInBank(0),
                     m_iThirst(0),
                     m_iFatigue(0),
                     m_pCurrentState(GoHomeAndSleepTilRested::Instance())
```

What exactly does this mean? It is declared under the class:

```
class Miner : public BaseGameEntity
```

btw... when ever I try to code blocks my code in this sight tab gets me out of this window :s how am I meant to?

Comment: I suppose it is a constructor with an initializer list.

Comment: @pmr, please convert your comment to an answer so that it can appear in searches etc.

Comment: This is basic C++ syntax. I recommend you grab a [good introductory C++ book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks).

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt like the ones that worked... I totally forgot I asked... I placed this late at night and forgot all about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the constructor of `Miner` class, using initialization list.

Refer to the following link for details of initialization list: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Answer (score 1):

It is a constructor definition with **ctor-initializer**.

Answer (score 0):

That's an initializer list - it instructs the compiler to initialize member variables to that values and call a specific constructor of the base class with passing it a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

It's the beginning of a constructor, and it is initalising the class members and base class. This is basic C++ syntax and should all be explained any C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of the constructor. Furthermore he assigns values to the class members: m_Location, etc.. and calls the base class constructor.

Comment: I would avoid the term "assign", when actually the initializer list *initializes* the member objects.